# How to create MBtiles from geoserver

Tags: qgis, geoserver, postgresql, sql-server

How to generate mbtiles in geoserver? using openlayers for displaying geoserver layer

for example calling wms layer like this

```
       new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Kanpur", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {
                LAYERS: 'sample_data_old:sample',
                STYLES: '',
                format: 'image/jpeg',
                tiled: false,
                transparent: true,
                tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom,
                visibility:false
                },
        { 
                isBaseLayer: true 
        }  
);
```

how can i call wps layer for creating mbtiles?

please refer this link for my question

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/mbtiles/output.html

Comment: You seem to be asking two different things. (a) how to create MBTiles which your link details, and (b) how to use them within Openlayers for displaying them. Why do you want to use OpenLayers to display the MBTiles? OpenLayers works best with PNG/JPEG/GIF, but you may want to see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33906/fixing-the-openlayers-mbtiles-example

Comment: From the [Tour] you will see that there should be only one question per question.  Here you have two which makes your question too broad.